# How to merge matched data and still display the unmatched data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes but not all records have the primary key.

DF1 is:

```
EmpID   SNcode  Name
A1      123     Bill
B2      456     Alice
                Carrie
```

DF1

[image]

DF2 is:

```
EmpID   Sncode  Name    Department
A1      123     Bill    Accounts
B2      456     Alice   CustService
        986     Peter
```

DF2
[image]

I want the result to be like this:

```
EmpID   SNcode  Name    Department
A1      123     Bill    Accounts
B2      456     Alice   CustService
                Carrie  
        986     Peter
```

Result
[image]

My code below doesn't work:

```
mydata <- merge(DF1, DF2, by="EmpID",all.y=TRUE)
```

Could you please help me how to fix this? I need Carrie and Peter appear in the results.

Comment: `mydata <- merge(DF1, DF2, by="EmpID",all =TRUE)` ?

Comment: Here is the code: library(dplyr)

DF1=read.csv('not_sep.csv', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
DF2=read.csv('pcr_sep.csv', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

mydata <- merge(DF1, DF2, by="EmpID",all.y=TRUE)

sapply(mydata, as.character)
mydata[is.na(mydata)] <- ""

str(mydata)

write.csv(mydata,"merge_np2.csv", row.names=FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

These are the important basic code functions that are important to learn and understand for coding in R.  There are three different functions used here that will get the code to output exactly the way you want.

First, know that the tables are named in the same order as you showed them. They are named here as, t1, t2, and t3.  With t3 being the desired output.  These tables t1 and t2 do not get changed and remain the same.

There are four types of joins.  You might read-up about these join types and then try practicing with them.  Here I used the `full_join()` function.  This joins the values from two of the objects ( t2 & t1 ) by their column names.  All values are joined together and nothing gets removed or left behind.  The tables, t1 and t2 remain unchanged after this join.

Then the function, `na.omit()` is used to remove the NA's from the joined data. You can see these NA's if you print t3 before running the `na.omit()` function.

Then the function, `rownames()` is used to remove the row numbers from the joined data.  The data in t3 is now cleaned-up and matches your desired output format.

The code and output follows:

```
t3 <- full_join(t2, t1)   # join 
t3 <- na.omit(t3)           # remove the NA's
rownames(t3) = NULL       # remove the column row numbers
t3                         # print the output
```

[image]